# How to complete Text to Speech .stop()

Tags: android, text-to-speech

Help me with small problem. I have `TextToSpeech mTTS;` variable and `setOnUtteranceProgressListener(...)` Then `SpeakText(...)` start speech part of text;
OnClick button I try to stop speech `SpeakStop()` but something was wrong ?! Speech stopped then fired `onDone()` and speech continue ... (sometimes Not)
How to .stop speech guaranteed ?!

```
TextToSpeech mTTS;
mTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() { ... }


mTTS.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
                bWaitForSpeakDone = false;
                // ...
                SpeakText(utteranceId); // speak next part text
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String utteranceId) {
                bWaitForSpeakDone = false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onStart(final String utteranceId) {
                bWaitForSpeakDone = true;
                // ...
            }
        });

void SpeakStop() {
        mTTS.stop();
        bWaitForSpeakStop = true;
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                boolean isException = false;
                AddDebugText("Wait for mTTS.stop()");
                while (mTTS.isSpeaking() || bWaitForSpeakDone) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // e.printStackTrace();
                        AddDebugText("Thread exception (");
                        // isException = true;
                    }
                }
                bWaitForSpeakStop = false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Show your speakText method

Comment: Post the solution you found as a proper **answer**. You can even accept it, if you like.